# Syntax Error when importing serial

Tags: python, syntax, serial-port

I'm pretty new to Python and wanted to try it out by making some stuff happen with my Arduino microcontroller. So I downloaded the serial library, placed it into the Lib folder and imported it into my programm. Unfortunately the import causes the following Syntax Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import serial
  File "C:\Python33\lib\serial\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from serial.serialwin32 import *
  File "C:\Python33\lib\serial\serialwin32.py", line 12, in <module>
    from serial import win32
  File "C:\Python33\lib\serial\win32.py", line 196
    MAXDWORD = 4294967295L # Variable c_uint
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am using Windows 7 64 Bit. How can I fix this? I don't find any other versions of the serial module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [2to3](http://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html) can help you here...

Comment: I converted the whole serial directory with 2to3 and now it works. Thank you!

Comment: @user2018648 , What was the commandline you used to fix it? I'm a total newb, but I used "python tools\scripts\2to3.py lib\serial" and still get the same error doing only "import serial"  Ahhh - got it... the -w flag to write changes!

Answer (score 0):

It may be that both python2.X and python3.X are on your PC. Please check whether the pyserial-2.X file exists in the python3 directory(Python3X\Lib\site-packages). If it does exist, please try to cut this file into the python2X directory and use the command

```
pip3 install pyserial
```